# How to find the period of this function?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, periodic-functions

I want to find the period for f(x) = 2cos(10x +1) - sin(4x -1).
If 10 = 2pi/Ta and 4 =2pi/Tb, then Ta = pi/5 and Tb = pi/2
the book says is just pi, why ?

Comment: Why don't you compute $f(x+\alpha)$ and determine the $\alpha$ such that $f(x+\alpha) = f(x)$?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

The periods of the $\cos$ function are

$$\frac \pi 5,2\frac\pi 5, 3\frac \pi 5, 4\frac \pi 5 ,\pi, ...$$

the periods of the $\sin$ function are

$$\frac \pi 2, \pi, 3\frac \pi 2,...$$

the smallest common one is $T=\pi$.

Comment: Thanks, i understand it now.